# batch to retrieve files within folders based on time interval taken from folder name

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, move, batch-processing

I am new to batch scripting. I am working on the following,

I have many folders named as follow

02_25-06_00
02_25-06_10
02_25-06_20
02_25-06_30
02_25-06_40
02_25-06_50
02_25-07_00

where 02 is the month, 25 is the date, 06 is the hours and 00 is the minutes

Within each of these files, there are two folders named A and B. Each of the these folders has 5 text files.

I need a batch script that gets a time interval, like 06:00 to 06:20 as input and displays all the text files within each of the two sub folders, as follows

02_25-06_00-A1.txt
02_25-06_00-A2.txt
02_25-06_00-A3.txt
02_25-06_00-A4.txt
02_25-06_00-A5.txt
02_25-06_00-B1.txt
02_25-06_00-B2.txt
02_25-06_00-B3.txt
02_25-06_00-B4.txt
02_25-06_00-B5.txt
02_25-06_10-A1.txt
02_25-06_10-A2.txt
02_25-06_10-A3.txt
02_25-06_10-A4.txt
02_25-06_10-A5.txt
02_25-06_10-B1.txt
02_25-06_10-B2.txt
02_25-06_10-B3.txt
02_25-06_10-B4.txt
02_25-06_10-B5.txt

Please help me in this batch script...

Comment: Do the `.txt` files have those actual filenames?

Comment: @foxidrive no, the text files are having different names, I need to rename that file with the time information

Comment: The solution by MC ND works here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set /p "start=Start (hh:mm): "
    set /p "end=End (hh:mm): "

    set "somewhere=%cd%"

    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /on /ad "%somewhere%"') do (
        if "%%b" geq "%start::=_%" if "%%b" leq "%end::=_%" (
            for %%c in ( "%somewhere%\%%a-%%b\a\*.*" "%somewhere%\%%a-%%b\b\*.*") do (
                for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ("%%~dpc.") do (
                    echo(%%a-%%b-%%~nxd%%~nxc
                )
            )
        )
    )

pause
```

Here is a batch file to create the test case folders and files:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5) do for %%b in (A B) do for %%c in (
02_25-06_00
02_25-06_10
02_25-06_20
02_25-06_30
02_25-06_40
02_25-06_50
02_25-07_00
) do md %%c\%%b 2>nul& type nul>%%c\%%b\%%a.txt
```

EDITED - Include code changes to adapt to new folder naming (stated in comments). Changes included:

- folder a = 9k (changes in `for %%c` files set)
- folder b = c2 (changes in `for %%c` files set)
- time named folders = hh-mm_hh-mm (changes in `for %%a` delims, hour comparision variable substitution, `for %%c` files set)

The rest of the code remains without changes

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /on /ad "%somewhere%"') do (
    if "%%b" geq "%start::=-%" if "%%b" leq "%end::=-%" (
        for %%c in ( "%somewhere%\%%a_%%b\9k\*.*" "%somewhere%\%%a_%%b\c2\*.*") do (
            for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ("%%~dpc.") do (
                echo(%%a-%%b-%%~nxd%%~nxc
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I added a script to create the folders and files mentions.  Your script works well.

Comment: @foxidrive thank you very much for the timely help. I am getting all the txt files listed. Is it possible to extract the files and put it in a separate folder ?

Comment: @Mrk, replace the `echo` line with `copy "%%~fc" "c:\targetFolder\%%a-%%b-%%~nxd%%~nxc"`

Comment: @foxidrive yes it worked. Thanks a lot for the reply. I am new to batch scripting. Could you please tell me, where I could learn batch scripting in online, so that I can start writing codes myself. :-)

Comment: Mrk, the code was MC ND's and I just added minor cosmetic changes. To learn batch scripting it is useful to follow a batch forum like www.dostips.com or Computer Hope etc, and read other simple scripts and ask questions in the forums.  The people monitoring these forums are usually quite happy to explain techniques and help you.  You can type `HELP` at a cmd prompt to see a list of commands, and also type `HELP COMMANDNAME` to get some explanation of how the command name works.  Another way is to type `commandname /?` like `find /?` or `set /?` or `for /?`

Comment: @MCND Thank you very much for your help. This code is going to be really helpful. Thanks a lot. Could you please suggest some websites, to learn batch scripting. @ foxidrive - thank you very much for your advice and help.

Comment: @MCND I am trying to rename the a and b folder to 9k and c2, I changed the code accordingly, but it is not extracting the files, is there anything else I want to do, to make it work...

Comment: @Mrk, the only change you need to do is `for %%c in ( "%somewhere%\%%a-%%b\9k\*.*" "%somewhere%\%%a-%%b\c2\*.*")`. There is no other place in code where inner folder names are directly referenced.

Comment: @MCND ya it worked. Thank you very much for the reply. Is there any good book on batch scripting ?. Please advice. I am not finding the online resources to be much useful.

Comment: @Mrk, sorry, i don't know any. I learned the old way: think, try and see what happens, think, back to first step (and that from MS-DOS 2.0!). Anyway, [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting) should be accesible enough to start.

Comment: @MCND Thank you for your advice. I will also try to analyze things in that way.

Comment: @MCND I am stuck up with the folder name, the folders are now named as 03-24_07-00  instead of 03_24-07_00. I tried to change the "%start::=-%" and "%end::=-%" , but it is not working. Any thought on this MCND...

Comment: @Mrk, yes, that change is necessary. But you have also changed the separator between the two hours. You need to also change the next line, replacing both `\%%a-%%b\` with `\%%a_%%b\` (for the a and b cases)

Comment: @MCND ya I changed that, but still I am not able to retrieve the files. This is my changed code `code     for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /on /ad "%somewhere%"') do (
        if "%%b" geq "%start::=-%" if "%%b" leq "%end::=-%" (
            for %%c in ( "%somewhere%\%%a_%%b\9k\*.*" ) do (
                for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ("%%~dpc.") do (
                     copy "%%~fc" "c:\data\%%a-%%b-%%~nxd%%~nxc"
                )
    )
        )
    ) `

Comment: @Mrk, you did not change the delimiter in the outter `for`. Code included in answer. Are you sure the final naming will not also change?

Comment: @MCND yes, the final naming will not change. I tried to change the delimiter in the outer for loop. Then also  it is not working.

Comment: @Mrk, i've adapted the code from foxydrive to create the structure with the new naming (`aa-bb_cc-dd\9k\n.txt` and executed my code (changed version) against it. It works.

Comment: @MCND yes, it is working fine. I am able to retrieve the files. Thank you very much for your timely help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MCND Hi Sir, found out a good resource to learn batch scripting - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm - just wanted to share it with you, so that you can also share it with others  : )